# How to migrate from geth to parity

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, parity

I am using geth on test network and I have wallet with test ETH there. Is there some step-by-step instruction how to migrate from geth to parity? 
I didn't manage to find a way how to

- a) select TEST-NET
- b) import my geth account, this is all I have found in the interface:

[image]

I have mist installed on my Windows 7 machine.

Answer (score 1):

`parity` *should* have automatically detected your account(s), but you can also import the `.json` files that `geth` creates. I [believe](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Managing-your-accounts) the wallets in Windows live in `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Ethereum\Keystore` (someone please correct me if I'm wrong; I don't use Windows). You may need to store the wallet as a decrypted file temporarily if `parity` does not support importing encrypted `.json` accounts. If you're not already using full disk encryption, I recommend creating a RAM disk to store the keys to prevent leaking key information.

You can select the chain `parity` uses using the --chain option. From the `parity` help:

```
  --chain CHAIN                    Specify the blockchain type. CHAIN may be either a
                                   JSON chain specification file or olympic, frontier,
                                   homestead, mainnet, morden, ropsten, classic, expanse,
                                   testnet, kovan or dev (default: foundation).
```